# convert jquery to javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert this jquery to javascript. 
Please help

```
    $(document).ready(function($){
    if ( $("#search_field").val().length > 0 ) 
    {
       $('*[data-role=activerecord_sortable]').activerecord_sortable();
    }
    });
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You have to show at least some effort...

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I can come up with, I don't know what your activerecord_sortable function is doing off the top of my head:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var searchField = document.getElementById('search_field');
    if(searchField.value) {
        searchField.dataset['data-role'] = activerecord_sortable();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I use a ruby gem and I think activerecord_sortable adds a class in a table where the attribute is  data-role=activerecord_sortable.

Comment: I updated the example slightly, is that more in the direction of what you're looking for?

Comment: In the if condition I need something like:
         if(searchField.value.length > 0) {
          **(get elemet where the attribute data-role = activerecord_sortable ).activerecord_sortable();**
           }

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it could look like using `addEventListener` and `querySelector`

*Note, the [`activerecord_sortable()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=activerecord_sortable) is Ruby*

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  if (document.querySelector('#search_field').value.length > 0 ) 
  {
    document.querySelector('*[data-role=activerecord_sortable]').activerecord_sortable();
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly

Comment: @IvaneGomarteli You're welcome